# WSO2 Identity server - keep getting "internal error - server connection terminated"

Tags: wso2, saml-2.0, wso2-identity-server

I am getting an "Internal error" when implementing SAML2.0 setup with WSO2 Identity server.

I am running the sample applications and the identity server plus the sample apps are running.

The pickup-dispatch application is running fine on the link `http://127.0.0.1:8080/saml2-web-app-pickup-dispatch.com/` and after clicking login, it redirects me to the identity server login page (expected).

I enter my credentials but on pressing login, it returns "internal error - server connection terminated" after telling me about redirection to the app as seen in the screenshots below.

**A snippet from the error trace is** `HTTP ERROR 500
Problem accessing /saml2-web-app-pickup-dispatch.com/home.jsp. Reason: Server Error
Caused by: javax.servlet.ServletException: org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.agent.exception.SSOAgentException: Signature validation failed for SAML2 Element`

**Complete error stack trace** - `https://gist.github.com/KalemaEdgar/ee9804df5f2786e30af8ad2bd3ccf0fc`

[image]

[image]

Comment: Do you get any error trace in the console? Please share them as well

Comment: This is what I see in the logs. How do I get or generate the signature 

`HTTP ERROR 500
Problem accessing /saml2-web-app-pickup-dispatch.com/home.jsp. Reason: Server Error

Caused by: javax.servlet.ServletException: org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.agent.exception.SSOAgentException: Signature validation failed for SAML2 Element`

Comment: Complete error trace is here - `https://gist.github.com/KalemaEdgar/ee9804df5f2786e30af8ad2bd3ccf0fc`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what finally worked for me on top of Piraveena's response.
Since it is a signature validation error, to fix it properly I needed to add the public key of the identity server (`<is-home>/repository/resources/security/wso2carbon.jks`) to the keystore in the `saml2-web-app-pickup-dispatch.com` app (`<app-location-in-tomcat>/WEB-INF/classes/wso2carbon.jks`)

But if you simply want to try out the sample, a quick workaround would be to replace the keystore in the sample app(`<app-location-in-tomcat>/WEB-INF/classes/wso2carbon.jks`) with the keystore of the WSO2 Identity Server (`<is-home>/repository/resources/security/wso2carbon.jks`)

I also encourage those using WSO2 Identity server to join this slack workspace `iam4developers.slack.com`

Answer (score 1):

This is due to the signature validation fails when IS verifies the signature of the SAML authentication request sent from the application.

**Option1:**

You can either disable signature validation from the management console. Navigate the Service Provider. Follow the below screenshot and **untick the Enable signature Validation** feature.

[image]

**Option2:**

You can export the public certifcate of the saml2-web-app-pickup-dispatch and add it into the management console. Keystore of the app is located into /WEB-INF/classes/ folder.

[image]

If the application exists in a tenant, you can refer this blog: https://medium.com/@piraveenaparalogarajah/trying-out-saml2-pick-up-dispatch-app-with-wso2-identity-server-in-a-tenant-20626ac4865a

Comment: Thanks Piraveena for this. I disabled the signature check and got `Error when processing authentication request. Please try login again`. Logging in did not work so I deleted the service provider config and re-created it. I am now getting the error below whenever I try to re-create the service provider. `Error while updating Service Provider: Inbound key: 'saml2-web-app-pickup-dispatch.com' of inbound auth type: 'samlsso' is already configured for the application :dispatch`.. Complete error is `Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.common.IdentityApplicationManagementClientException`

Comment: Were  you able try to create with another name? Do you get any error logs?

Comment: When I attempt to create a new one (nomatter which service provider name I give), it returns `Could not add service provider. You might be entering a duplicate service Provider`
**Screenshot of the error** - https://gist.github.com/KalemaEdgar/72140df897f0a15af1c86a13fce714ea#gistcomment-3233145
**Complete error** - https://gist.github.com/KalemaEdgar/72140df897f0a15af1c86a13fce714ea

Comment: **Note** - I am using `Issuer` as `saml2-web-app-pickup-dispatch.com` and the `Assertion Consumer URL` as `http://localhost.com:8080/saml2-web-app-pickup-dispatch.com/home.jsp`

Comment: So I managed to create another service provider when I change the issuer Id but when I send the request, I pick this up in the logs instead `[2020-03-30 19:26:19,270] [883b8108-6469-4592-b9d1-686d4ca1cb82]  WARN {org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.saml.validators.SPInitSSOAuthnRequestValidator} - A Service Provider with the Issuer 'saml2-web-app-pickup-dispatch.com' is not registered. Service Provider should be registered in advance.`